Is it possible to get rid of msixbackgroundtasksexecutor while still using Skype?
Not long ago I turned on Skype, which updated itself and installed a process called msixbackgroundtasksexecutor. Ever since, this process has been running in the background, without showing up in the startup apps – and I couldn't find a service that runs it either. This happens even when Skype is completely off.
Moreover, if I prevent this process from accessing the Internet, it eventually restarts and runs as a new process.
Is it possible to get rid of this process, while still keeping the ability to use Skype when needed? Is there a setting that would prevent it from running within Skype?
Using Windows 11 Pro 23H2.
